# How to update a mongodb document depending on values of document referenced by its objectId

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, reference, mongodb-query

How can I update a MongoDB document depending on values of document referenced by it's objectId? (I am using MongoDB via mongoose)

Let's assume I have two collections. One is called competitions and the other one is called games. A competition can have several games in it. See code example below

```
// competition documents
[
    {
        compeititionName:"myCompetition",
        games:["617...b16", "617...b19", "617...b1c",
        competitionStatus:"notStarted",
    },
    {
        compeititionName:"yourCompetition",
        games:["617...b18", "617...b19", "617...b1c",
        competitionStatus:"playing",
    },
    {
        compeititionName:"ourCompetition",
        games:["617...b14", "617...b19", "617...b2b",
        competitionStatus:"ended",
    }

]
```

The `competitionStatus` above is dependent on the status of the games in that competition.

If all the games have not started then the competition should have `notStarted` as its `competitionStatus`. However if any of the games is being played or there are games which have not started and others which are complete then the competition status should be `playing`. Finally if all the games have ended the the competition status should be `ended`. An example of how the games collection would look is:

```
// game documents
[
    {
        _id:"617...b16",
        gameStatus:"notStarted"
    },
    {
        _id:"617...b18",
        gameStatus:"playing"
    },
    {
        _id:"617...b14",
        gameStatus:"ended"
    },
]
```

How can I update the `competitionStatus` given the `_id` of the game whose status has just changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is mongoose, you select the model you want to update first:

```
const completion = await CompletionModel.FindOne({games: _id_of_the_game});
```

Then aggregate statuses of all games:

```
const statuses = await GameModel.aggregate([
  {$match: {_id: {$in: completion.games}}},
  {$group: {_id: gameStatus}}
]).toArray();
```

Then apply your business logic to set the status:

```
if(statuses.leength === 1) { // all games have same status
  if(statuses[0]._id === "notStarted") {
    completion.competitionStatus = "notStarted";
  } elseif (statuses[0]._id === "ended") {
    completion.competitionStatus = "ended";
  } else {
    completion.competitionStatus = "playing";
} else {
  completion.competitionStatus = "playing";
}
```

Then save it to the db:

```
await completion.save();
```

Please bear in mind, this pseudo-code is prone to race conditions - if games change status between `aggregate()` and `save()` you may end up with stale status in completion documents. You may want to add extra queries to ensure data consistency if required.

#### UPDATE

If a `game` can be in more than 1 `completion` then using Mongoose will be quite inefficient. Starting from v4.2 you can use [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-merge) aggregation stage to do all calculations on the database side, and update matched documents:

```
db.competition.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      games: "id_of_the_game"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "games",
      let: {
        g: "$games"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$_id",
                "$$g"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$gameStatus"
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "statuses"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      competitionStatus: {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$gt": [
              {
                "$size": "$statuses"
              },
              1
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            _id: "playing"
          },
          "else": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$statuses",
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      competitionStatus: "$competitionStatus._id"
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "competition"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: I have accepted this answer although I meant how to update a number of competition documents not just one.  I guess I'll just have to loop through to update them.

Comment: Sorry, I missed  the fact that a game may be in multiple completions. I'd recommend to go with  bare mongo query rather than Mongoose models. Please see my update.

Comment: Yes, $merge is what I need. Thank you. Mongoose supports aggregation too.